# Profiling trivial loop

Tags: haskell, profiling

I am trying to understand how to use performance profiling. Here is a solution for problem "Line of sight" from USACO 2013.

```
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.List
import Data.Int

angle !a | a > 2 * pi = a - 2 * pi
angle !a | a < 0      = a + 2 * pi
angle !a              = a

tans :: Int64 -> [[Int64]] -> UArray (Int,Int) Double
tans r cs = listArray ((0,0), (length cs - 1, 1)) $ concatMap f cs where
  f :: [Int64] -> [Double]
  f [x,y] = [angle a2, angle a1] where
    phi | y == 0    = if x < 0 then pi else 0.0
        | otherwise = (fromIntegral $ signum y) * (acos $ (fromIntegral x) / d)
    d = sqrt $ fromIntegral $ x*x + y*y
    z = sqrt $ fromIntegral $ x*x + y*y - r*r
    a1 = phi + (acos $ (fromIntegral r)/d)
    a2 = phi - (acos $ (fromIntegral r)/d)

overlap !a1 !a2 !a1' !a2'
   | a1 < a2 && a1' < a2' = a1 <= a2' && a1' <= a2
   | a1 > a2 && a1' > a2' = overlap (a1 - 2*pi) a2 (a1' - 2*pi) a2'
   | a1 > a2 && a1' <= pi = overlap (a1 - 2*pi) a2 a1'          a2'
   | a1 > a2              = overlap a1 (a2 + 2*pi) a1'          a2'
   | a1 <= pi             = overlap a1          a2 (a1' - 2*pi) a2'
   | otherwise            = overlap a1          a2 a1'          (a2' + 2 * pi)

solve cows = length $ [ 1
                      | i <- [0..n]
                      , j <- [i+1..n]
                      , let a1 = cows ! (i,0)
                      , let a2 = cows ! (i,1)
                      , let a1' = cows ! (j,0)
                      , let a2' = cows ! (j,1)
                      , overlap a1 a2 a1' a2' ] where
  ((0,0),(n,1)) = bounds cows

main = do
         ls <- getContents
         let ([n, r]: cows ) = map (map read . words) $ lines ls
         print $ solve $ tans r cows
```

I am using example dataset 5.in from http://www.usaco.org/current/data/sight.zip and get the following profile:

```
$ ghc -O2 -XBangPatterns -ddump-simpl sight3.hs
$ ./sight3 < 5.in
...
    Sun Dec 01 23:35 2013 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       sight3.EXE +RTS -p -hd -RTS

    total time  =       10.46 secs   (10459 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 1,847,301,536 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE  %time %alloc

solve       Main     65.2   30.7
overlap     Main     14.4    0.0
solve.a2'   Main      8.9   32.5
solve.a1'   Main      8.6   32.5
main.(...)  Main      2.8    4.0


                                                            individual     inherited
COST CENTRE    MODULE                     no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN           MAIN                        49           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main          Main                        99           0    0.0    0.1    99.9  100.0
  main.r       Main                       110           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  tans         Main                       105           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.1
   tans.f      Main                       106       10000    0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
    tans.f.a1  Main                       112       10000    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    angle      Main                       111       20000    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    tans.f.d   Main                       109       10000    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    tans.f.phi Main                       108       10000    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    tans.f.a2  Main                       107       10000    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  solve        Main                       104           1   65.2   30.7    97.1   95.7
   overlap     Main                       117    64368980   14.4    0.0    14.4    0.0
   solve.a2'   Main                       116    49995000    8.9   32.5     8.9   32.5
   solve.a1'   Main                       115    49995000    8.6   32.5     8.6   32.5
   solve.a2    Main                       114        9999    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   solve.a1    Main                       113        9999    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  solve.(...)  Main                       103           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  solve.n      Main                       102           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main.cows    Main                       101           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main.(...)   Main                       100           1    2.8    4.0     2.8    4.0
 CAF           GHC.IO.Encoding.CodePage    83           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF           GHC.IO.Handle.Internals     82           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF           Text.Read.Lex               79           0    0.1    0.0     0.1    0.0
 CAF           GHC.IO.Encoding             75           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF           GHC.Int                     71           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF           GHC.IO.Handle.FD            67           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main1     Main                        63           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main         Main                        98           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:lvl3_r3iU Main                        59           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

- what is being allocated in solve.a1' and a2'? I thought that being strict, it won't allocate anything (and the computation is no different from solve.a1)
- how to find out where the CPU is spent in solve? I'd expect the most cost being spent in overlap, and the enclosing loop to be very cheap in comparison.

(for the sake of stray reader, I add that this is purely a profiling exercise - I do have a solution that is hundreds of times faster, but it is boring from a profiling perspective even with plain lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ghc does not manage to fold the length computation with building the list - i.e. it allocates list cells.

If you rewrite `solve` to an explicit loop, the allocations vanish:

```
solve cows = n `seq` go 0 0 1 n
  where
    (_,(n,_)) = bounds cows
    go count i j n | i > n = count
                   | j > n = go count (i+1) (i+2) n
                   | overlap (cows ! (i,0)) (cows ! (i,1)) (cows ! (j,0)) (cows ! (j,1))
                       = go (count + 1) i (j + 1) n
                   | otherwise = go count i (j + 1) n
```

As to why the allocations are attributed to a1' and a2', I have no clue.

Cpu use is dominated by the `go` function, which probably means array access. `overlap` is only about 15% of total run time.

Edit: here's (less readable) version with two of the array accesses moved out of the inner loop:

```
solve !cows = n `seq` go 0 0
 where
  (_,(n,_)) = bounds cows
  go !count !i | i >= n = count
               | otherwise = go2 count i (i+1) (cows ! (i,0)) (cows ! (i,1))
  go2 !count !i !j !a1 !a2 | j > n = go count (i+1)
                           | overlap a1 a2 (cows ! (j,0)) (cows ! (j,1))
                                  = go2 (count+1) i (j+1) a1 a2
                           | otherwise = go2 count i (j+1) a1 a2
```

Comment: I have a problem with this. 1. array access costing 4x more than a series of tests? 2. if that is all, why it runs for 3 seconds? (or over 15 seconds for 6.in - that's just a few million array accesses and comparisons) 3. allocations still are attributed to a1, a2, a1' and a2' (I kept them instead of supplying arguments directly) 4. rewriting with "go" didn't speed up the program

Comment: You didn't ask about speeding up the program, but only where allocations and time go. And while the data in 5.in should fit into L2 cache, accessing that can still take a lot of time compared to some branches (assuming a high branch prediction rate).

Comment: Note that my version is actually slower than the original because the array accesses with index i are not moved out of the inner j loop. Adding a faster version. Also, compile FP code with -fllvm

Comment: A C version is only 3 times faster - to get the Haskell version faster, you'll need to do low-level code tuning. Profiling the C version shows 80% time in overlap, btw. Gist: https://gist.github.com/bokesan/7750850

Comment: Yes, I didn't ask to speed up the program; but I'd expect the proof "where the problem was" to show that by changing the execution speed :) ok, I'll try the -fllvm

Comment: Also, the original point of the question was to understand what you see that makes you conclude what optimizations to apply.

Comment: IMO, you had the correct approach for numeric code: first make sure that there are no allocations, then look where the time is spent. I think that the problem with this example is that it's already quite close to optimal - if all my Haskell could would be within factor 2 of the equivalent C code, I'd be happy.